# Custom Camera view using ZXING in Portrait Mode. Android

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am trying to use a custom barcode reader in portrait mode using Zxing library.

It's easy to set orientation: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/253

And I have seen you can customize a Camera Preview with minimal library:

https://medium.com/@marta/bar-code-scanner-in-android-with-custom-layout-zxing-2ab92d9d744c

https://github.com/Promptus/zxing-android-minimal

Is there any way to use both? or maybe other solution? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the BarcodeView of the Zxing Library in your own Activity. This gives you the possibility to style the scanner and control the orientation.

https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/zxing-android-embedded/src/com/journeyapps/barcodescanner/BarcodeView.java